# Why is a projection matrix of an orthogonal projection symmetric?

Tags: regression, least-squares

I am quite new to this, so I hope you forgive me if the question is naïve. (Context: I am learning econometrics from Davidson & MacKinnon's book ["Econometric Theory and Methods"](http://econ.queensu.ca/ETM/), and they do not seem to explain this; I've also looked at [Luenberger's](http://books.google.com/books/about/Optimization_by_vector_space_methods.html?id=lZU0CAH4RccC) optimization book that deals with projections at an a bit more advanced level, but with no luck).

Suppose that I have an orthogonal projection $\mathbb P$ with is associated projection matrix $\bf P$. I am interested in projecting each vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ into some subspace $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

*Question*: why does it follow that $\bf{P}=P$$^T$, that is, $\bf P$ is symmetric? What textbook could I look at for this result?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a fundamental results from linear algebra on orthogonal projections. A relatively simple approach is as follows. If $u_1, \ldots, u_m$ are orthonormal vectors spanning an $m$-dimensional subspace $A$, and $\mathbf{U}$ is the $n \times p$ matrix with the $u_i$'s as the columns, then 
$$\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T.$$
This follows directly from the fact that the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $A$ can be computed in terms of the orthonormal basis of $A$ as
$$\sum_{i=1}^m u_i u_i^T x.$$
It follows directly from the formula above that $\mathbf{P}^2 = \mathbf{P}$ and that $\mathbf{P}^T = \mathbf{P}.$

It is also possible to give a different argument. If $\mathbf{P}$ is a projection matrix for an orthogonal projection, then, by definition, for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ 
$$\mathbf{P}x \perp y-\mathbf{P}y.$$
Consequently,
$$0 = (\mathbf{P} x)^T (y - \mathbf{P}y) = x^T \mathbf{P}^T (I - \mathbf{P}) y = x^T (\mathbf{P}^T - \mathbf{P}^T \mathbf{P}) y $$
for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. This shows that $\mathbf{P}^T = \mathbf{P}^T \mathbf{P}$, whence 
$$\mathbf{P} = (\mathbf{P}^T)^T = (\mathbf{P}^T \mathbf{P})^T = \mathbf{P}^T \mathbf{P} = \mathbf{P}^T.$$

Comment: Thanks for your insightful comment(s)! Somehow the Wikipedia article, which mentioned something about self-adjointness of the projection operator threw me off, as your proofs are not that difficult. :) BTW, do you have a favorite linear algebra text that deals with this kind of stuff?

Comment: The elementary linear algebra book I know the best does not cover this. The best references I know are advanced books on functional analysis. The [Linear algebra done right](http://books.google.com/books?id=ovIYVIlithQC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) book looks good, but I don't know it.

Comment: A note: NRH's answer assumes that $x = x^T$.
That is, the only case in which $(Px)^T = xP^T$ (as claimed in the equality $(Px)^T(y-Py)=xP^T(I-P)y$) is when $x = x^T$ because for any linear map $P$ and vector $x$, $$(Px)^T = x^TP^T.$$
This does not affect really the result of the proof, as the implication that $P^T - P^TP = 0$ holds in both cases, but I thought it would be worth mentioning.

Comment: @Milan Thank you for noticing.  Observe that $x=x^T$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is possible only when $n=1$, which is uninteresting. What happened simply is that a few transposes were lost on the $x$'s in the penultimate line.  I have restored the missing transposes to make the algebra correct.

Comment: It is not enough characters for me to be able to edit it, but $\mathbf{U}$ is an $n \times m$ matrix; not an $n \times p$ matrix. Not sure where $p$ came from.

Answer (score 3):

An attempt at geometrical intuition... 
Recall that:

1. A symmetric matrix is self adjoint.
2. A scalar product is determined only by the components in the **mutual** linear space (and independent of the orthogonal components of any of the vectors).

What you want to "see" is that a projection is self adjoint thus symmetric-- following (1). Why is this so?
Consider the scalar product of a vector $x$ with the projection $A$ of a second vector $y$: $ \langle x,Ay \rangle$. Following (2), the product will depend only on the components of $x$ in the span of the projection of $y$. So the product should be the same as $\langle Ax,Ay \rangle$, and also $\langle Ax,y\rangle $ following the same argument.

Since $A$ is self adjoint- it is symmetric.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Before reading your comment, I was quite confused about why self-adjointness is crucial here. Now I have some clue, thanks!